# yes/no атрибут в Magento

Tags: cms, magento, атрибуты

Хочу вывести в list.phtml  атрибут "Новинка" и "Топ продаж" через атрибут выборки yes/no. Выглядит это как картинка в верхнем левом углу со словом, то есть названиме, атрибута. что прописать, что бы при выборе yes появлялся атрибут с нужной картинокй?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может кому то в помощь

```
<?php $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('название вашего атрибута'); ?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
<?php if ($attribute_value == 'Yes'): ?>
    <div>Новинка</div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```